# Application crashes on debugging a web project with exit code -2147023895 (0x800703e9) in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to debug a web api project on a newly setup laptop with Visual studio 2017 professional edition.

It uses Target framework of `.NET Framework 4.6.1`.

The web application (not visual studio) crashes few seconds after starting with this in the output window.

> The program '[4868] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).

And for every crash, I see this message in Event Viewer

> The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> (devenv.exe, PID 24968, Thread 1) IdleProcessorManager.DoWork - Job threw:
>   Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. at
>      at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
>      at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestCaseManagement.SolutionIntegrationManager.IsRunConfig(String filename)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestCaseManagement.SolutionIntegrationManager.d__351.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestCaseManagement.IdleProcessorManager.DoWork()
>
> The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table

I already tried deleting .vs folder, restarting pc, uninstall/install vs, uninstall/install .net framework amongst other things.

Can someone help me fix this, unable to get to the 'real' reason for these failures.

Things to note - 
 1. The project works fine on other machines.
 2. I can create a new project using project template and run/debug application successfully.

EDIT : On more investigation I find that the web application breaks (without any error other than the exit code) and exits.

```
public virtual DataSet Execute(SqlCommand sqlCommand, SqlConnection sqlConnection)
{
    if (sqlCommand == null || sqlConnection == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var ds = new DataSet();

    if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
    }

    using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
    {
        adp.Fill(ds); <---- BREAKS here!
        return ds;
    }
}
```

On another machine where its working, it works perfectly fine. And the SP returns around 390K records. Possible stackoverflow exception?

Comment: So, Visual Studio crashes or does your web api crash?

Comment: What is the uri string?

Comment: Try to run it with debugging from visual studio. In that case thrown exception will be cached by VS and there you can investigate issue.

Comment: Visual studio crashes. The site is configured to use `http://localhost:8888/`. @RandRandom

Comment: Your comment says "Visual Studio crashes" but you edited your question to "The web application (not visual studio) crashes" - which leaves me totally confused...

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I ll update that.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the Framework **versions** that are **installed** to your new laptop.
I suspect that the minor versions don't match wiht your new laptop.

You can check which versions are installed to your machine via the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Edit:
1- Install the version from :
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49981

2- Or I recommend you to upgrade your Project's framework to .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Using the link I found this version is installed -> `.NET Framework 4.7.2`. What do I do next? :(

Comment: No didnt help. Plan to do a factory reset of my machine and install only the needed framework.